# How to find the parameters of custom regression in python code?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science-model

I want to make a time series regression that has a custom formula lets say:

Yt=Beta+1/(1+(some parameter sigma))*Y(t-1)+(1/(1+(some parameter sigma))**2)*Y(t-2)+Beta1*X(t-1)+Beta2*X(t-2)

how to code this in Python. Where to find help for future ideas?